# Django Imagefield not saved

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Although I select images in the form, image changes do not saved. Other inputs are saving. Help me pls.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{settingform}}
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class SiteSetting(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, verbose_name="Logo")

    @property
    def logo_url(self):
        if self.logo and hasattr(self.logo, 'url'):
            return self.logo.url
```

views.py:

```
def SiteSettingsView(request):
    settings = SiteSetting.objects.all()
    settingform = SiteSettingForm(instance=settings[0])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        settingform = SiteSettingForm(request.POST, instance=settings[0])
        if settingform.is_valid():
            settingform.save()
            return redirect('home')
    context = {
        'settings': settings[0],
        'settingform': settingform
    }
    return render(request, 'x.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from site_setting.models import SiteSetting

class SiteSettingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteSetting
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have also to provide `request.FILES` to the `SiteSettingForm`:

```
settingform = SiteSettingForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=settings[0])
```

See [**Basic file uploads**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) ([Django-Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads))